# Why isn't this PHP code working?

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I cannot for the life of me figure out why this code is not working!

For some reason, when I submit the form, the header does not redirect me to `./index?succes#generalSet`. However, it worked in an older version of this page. Using exactly the same code.

**Code:**

```
<span>
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
        echo 'Details have been updated!<br>
              Please allow up to 7 minutes for changes to take effect.';
    } else {
    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
        $update_data = array(
            'first_name'     => $_POST['first_name'],
            'last_name'      => $_POST['last_name'],
            'email'          => $_POST['email'],
            'description'    => $_POST['description']
        );

        update_user($session_user_id, $update_data);
        header('Location: index?success#generalSet');
        exit();

    } else if (empty($errors) === false) {
        echo output_errors($errors);
    }
    ?>
</span>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;padding-top:50px;margin-left:-40px;">
        <li>
            First Name*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['first_name']; ?>"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
            Last Name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $user_data['last_name']; ?>"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
            Email*:<br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $user_data['email']; ?>"><br>
        </li>
        <li>
            Description:<br>
            <textarea type="text" rows="7" cols="42" value="<?php echo $user_data['description']; ?>" name="description"></textarea><br>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save"><br>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Where is your `update_user` function??

Comment: may be problem is there!!

Comment: nope. @Saty as stated above, it worked in my other page

Comment: @Saty but why isn't the header redirecting me?? :(

Comment: put some echoes here and there and check how many echoes it reaches

Comment: header sometimes don't work if some html code is already above it make sure header code is above all html code and all `echo`'es

Comment: @RooshanAkthar where, for what reason & what's that going to help with?

Comment: May be you code fail before header!!

Comment: @Saty triple checked. no problems

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic to check whether the code reaches up to the redirect point.

Comment: Is you forget `.php` in `index?success#generalSet` ??

Comment: @Saty nah, I have htaccess file allowing it, but yes, I have tried doing it that way.

Comment: @RooshanAkthar tried that, it was reaching them? :/

Comment: Can you show us your last version of code which worked?

Answer (score 2):

Your header code:

```
header('Location: index?success#generalSet');
```

needs to appear before *any* HTML output. However earlier in the document you have (at least):

```
<span>
```

You need to move the header output, and all associated logic, to a place in the file prior to any HTML output being sent. This is because the HTTP spec does not allow headers to be adjusted after content is sent - headers need to be at the start.

To solve this problem it is comment to structure a page thus:

```
<?php

// Logic here, including redirects

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <!-- content here -->
</html>
```

If you have previously got this to work, it is possible that PHP stored some of your content in the output buffer before flushing it to the web server. If so, this will have allowed PHP to inject headers into the connection prior to sending the content. However, if you find that this works, I would not recommend you rely upon it: headers should always be sent before content.

---

Update: a helpful commenter below pointed out this code clause:

```
   if (isset($_GET['success']) === true && empty($_GET['success']) === true) {
        echo 'Details have been updated!<br>
          Please allow up to 7 minutes for changes to take effect.';
   } else {
```

This counts as HTML output as well, and could well prevent the header from working. In any case, why write to the screen if you intend to redirect immediately anyway? In general you should use the session if you want a message to persist across HTTP operations.

Comment: It is possible that your content had been cached in a PHP buffer and not yet flushed to the connection. Unless you are explicitly controlling the buffer ([and PHP does allow this](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php)) I do not recommend you rely on this - the above sample is just much more reliable.

Comment: @CaelanGrgurovic It shouldn't if you have same type of <span> before header in that page also.

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't a complete fault report @Caelan. It _will_ work if you ensure that you are not sending content before the header - maybe you are still sending something? Show us what you now have, code-wise, and we can go from there.

Comment: It's still doing the exact same thing, I have put it all before my HTML, even though it is not supposed to function like that. And It still did not go as planned

Comment: @TareqMahmood no, I have error_reporting enabled too

Comment: Alright @Caelan, well ping me if you can show what you have. You may have some other error affecting the application. If you write a small demo script _just_ containing a header, it will work, unless you have some problem with your web server.

Comment: Good spot @Rooshan - that counts as output as well! (in response to your now deleted comment)

Comment: @RooshanAkthar when I manually input ?success=true or just ?success into the url, yes it does work

Comment: Sorry for the delete. He uses a If Condition there. so it won't output it. else condition has the redirect. 

@CaelanGrgurovic do like this. `echo "1";` before `header()` and view the source. can you see any output in the source before `1`

Comment: @Rooshan: fair enough. I'll leave my edit in the answer though, since it illustrates very well how content output can generally still occur when one is not expecting it `:-)`.

Comment: @halfer I noticed your edit. but my code kind of works like a loop. So that I redirects if it meets all of the criteria, but It redirects to the current webpage, but I gets rid of the form and displays the message instead. If that makes any sense?

Comment: It sort of makes sense @Caelan. If you have moved this whole block to the start of the page, you will now have to set boolean variables so that you can output things (e.g. `Details have been updated`) in the correct places in the HTML.

Comment: Incidentally @Caelan, I have a substantial tutorial (see my profile) that will help with teaching good-practice structure if you are building without a framework. There's a lot to learn, but I think you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

The answer as to why this may have worked previously, but is not working now, probably resides in your PHP configuration. PHP has a [`output_buffering`](http://php.net/outcontrol.configuration#ini.output-buffering) directive, which can allow PHP to buffer output up to certain length before trying to send this output to the client. This means that if you had this directive high enough at any point prior where the code was working, you would not get the **`PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... (output started at ...)`** error that you are probably getting now. As mentioned in the other answer, you should always try to set your headers before sending any output.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that output buffering could be switched on by default - that might explain why it works on one app but not another - perhaps they use separate configurations.